# .htaccess Redirect from URL with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I am in the process of redirecting outdated URLs to their new URL.

I dynamically generate the product page URLs using the following three RewriteRules:

```
# PRODUCT SUB-CATEGORY REDIRECT -- Must follow syntax: domain.com/products/CATEGORY/SUB-CATEGORY
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /product-subcategory.php?category=$1&sub-category=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

# PRODUCT CATEGORY REDIRECT -- Must follow syntax: domain.com/products/CATEGORY
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]*)$ /product-category.php?category=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

# PRODUCT CATEGORY REDIRECT WITH PAGE NUMBER
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]*)/page/([^/]*)$ /product-category.php?category=$1&page=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

The **above** methods work correctly.

Now, I am trying to redirect the old URL structure shown here:

```
http://example.com/company/categories.cfm?c=Standard_Cabinet
```

To the new page, shown here:

```
http://example.com/products/standard-cabinets
```

I tried this `RewriteRule`, with no success:

```
RewriteRule ^company/categories.cfm?c=Standard_Cabinet$ http://www.example.com/products/standard-cabinets [R=301,NC]
```

I just keep getting redirected to my `404` page. I do not need to keep the old URL parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=Standard_Cabinet$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^company/categories\.cfm$ http://www.example.com/products/standard-cabinets? [R=301,NC]
```